# How do I remove all white space in any given input?

Tags: python

How do I remove all white space in any given input? For example:

```
askuser = input("Enter A Sentence:")  # --> fdshjh jfdhsj nhhsfd sdh hsfdjh shdks
```

Comment: ...and what should the output be? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't elegant, but you could strip line endings, then replace the spaces and tabs:

```
askuser = askuser.strip().replace(' ','').replace('\t','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the regular expression character set that represents all whitespace in the following manner:

```
new_input = re.sub(r'\s+', '', input('Enter A Sentence: ')) # whitespace is now empty str
```

Comment: @EzanaTesfaye Please mark as answer with the check mark on the side.